# Android iText pdf is generating in emulator but not on device

Tags: android, pdf, itext, device

I am generating a `pdf` document using `itext` in my app. I made sure to download the android version from the site.

When I run the app in the emulator (without connecting the phone), generate the document and pull it from the SD card in eclipse using `"Pull from device"`, everything works fine. When i installed (sideloaded) the app onto a phone and generated the pdf from the phone, the app showed a success message and created the document in the SD card. I have also clicked on order and export when building the path.

My problem is that when i create the document on the phone the following errors when i try to open it with `Adobe Reader` `"The document is empty (size 0KB)`. I don't know what goes wrong on the phone because in the emulator(without connecting the phone) it works fine. I have added the jar to the build path and `libs` folder. I've browsed the internet for solutions but couldn't find one. Maybe it has something to do with my `classpath`. I'm using `iText`.Here's my code for my `classpath`:

```
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/itextpdf-5.3.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Here's my code to generate the pdf:

```
public void createPDF(String title, String summary, String overview, String marketing, String mgmt, 
          String assets, String financial) {
      String filePath = file + ".pdf";
    try {
      Document document=new Document();

      File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Plans");
        if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
                }

      File path = new File(root, filePath);         
      PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(path));      
      document.open();

      addMetaData(document); //methods i created for the layout of the document
      addTitlePage(document, title);
      addSummary(document, summary);
      addOverview(document, overview);
      addAssets(document, assets);
      addMarketing(document, marketing);
      addManagement(document, mgmt);     
      addFinancial(document, financial);

      document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to share the stack trace. You'll probably see a ClassNotFoundException because you didn't package iText with your APK, but that's a wild guess. You shouldn't expect an answer if you don't add extra info to your question.

Comment: Furthermore: you're using the Java iText instead of iTextG: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextg (I know because the jar you use is itextpdf-5.3.4.jar instead of itextg-5.3.4.jar)